# Select Visual FoxPro Search a dbf meanwhile is connected to an sql database

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

In a simple program where i connect from visual foxpro to a sql server with the connectionstring and i have already controlled if is connected successfully when i create a simple select command with the name of the table from the database the program try to search the table in local and expect me to give him a dbf file meanwhile the table is in the database in sql

```
Select * FROM table Where column=k into cursor nnn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. That piece of code you supplied is just a query done against a VFP table\cursor in your local. It has nothing to do with an SQL server query. Here is a sample doing an SQL server query using sample Northwind database:

```
LOCAL lnHandle, lcCountry
lnHandle = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes")

lcCountry = "USA"
SQLEXEC(m.lnHandle, "Select * from Customers where Country = ?m.lcCountry", "crsCustomers")

SQLDISCONNECT(m.lnHandle)

SELECT crsCustomers
browse
```

This is an SPT query. There is also CursorAdapter, in which you could use ODBC or OLEDB.

Please explain what you are really asking if that wasn't what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a connection string to a VFP database. This does not mean that you can then just query any table on the SQL server in a regular SELECT statement. Instead you create a remote view with your query and then open the remote view like a table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the SQL server before feeding in the query

```
MyCon="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=000.000.000.000;PORT=0000;DATABASE=????; USER=???;PASSWORD=???;OPTION=?;"

xCon = SQLSTRINGCONNECT(MyCon)
IF xCon <= 0
    MESSAGEBOX("Connection Error",0+16, "Error")
ELSE
    *SQL Query
    msql= "Select * FROM table Where column=k into cursor nnn"
    SQLEXEC(xCon, msql, "Cursor")
    SQLDISCONNECT(xCon)
ENDIF
```

You will need to fill in the server, port and anywhere I have put ??? with the information for your own SQL server.

"Cursor" is the name of the cursor that your select statement will create and can be accessed outside of the SQL Connect.